# Show Progress loadTransferable<T>

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to show on UI the current progress of video processing due new rules in WWDC2022.

Property:

```
@State private var videoProcessing: Progress?
```

The `Transferrable`:

```
struct VideoPickerTranserable: Transferable {
    let videoUrl: URL
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { exportingFile in
            .init(exportingFile.videoUrl)
        } importing: { ReceivedTransferredFile in
            let originalFile = ReceivedTransferredFile.file
            let copiedFile = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "videoPicker.mov")
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copiedFile.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copiedFile)
            }

            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: originalFile, to: copiedFile)
            return .init(videoUrl: copiedFile)
        }
    }
}
```

Catching the progress:

```
self.videoProcessing = newValue.loadTransferable(type: VideoPickerTranserable.self) { result in                            
switch result {
           case .success(let success):
                if let success {
                    self.pickedVideoUrl = success.videoUrl
                    isVideoProcessing = false
                 }
           case .failure:
                 isVideoProcessing = false
                  break
    }
```

And `ProgressView`:

```
                    ProgressView(value: Double(videoProcessing!.completedUnitCount), total: Double(videoProcessing!.totalUnitCount))
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: 50)
                        .progressViewStyle(.linear)
```

But it doesn't work. How to catch this progress??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It isn’t provided

Comment: what does it mean? The official docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress

Comment: I know what the docs say, load transferable doesn’t actually provide an updating progress. You can get a progress but it doesn’t update, even if you use KVO (old approach)